# On the Meaning of Tensor Components (And Whether a Certain Computation Is Correct)

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

I've been recently following [Lecture 8 of Frederic Schuller's Geometrical Anatomy of Theoretical Physics Lecture Series](https://youtu.be/4l-qzZOZt50). He defines the components of a type $(p, q)$ tensor as

$$T^{a_1 \dots a_p}_{b_1 \dots b_q} \equiv T(\epsilon^{a_1}, \dots ,\epsilon^{a_p}, e_{b_1}, \dots, e_{b_q}),$$
and then claims that it's easy to show that $$T = T^{a_1 \dots a_p}_{b_1 \dots b_q}(e_{a_1} \otimes \dots \otimes e_{a_p} \otimes \epsilon^{b_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \epsilon^{b_q})$$ where $\{e_i\}$ are the basis vectors on V and $\{\epsilon^j \}$ is the dual basis on $V^{*}$. When I attempt to show that I get,
\begin{align*} 
&T^{a_1 \dots a_p}_{b_1 \dots b_q}(e_{a_1} \otimes \dots \otimes e_{a_p} \otimes \epsilon^{b_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \epsilon^{b_q})(w_1, \dots ,w_p, v_1, \dots, v_q) \\
&= T(\epsilon^{a_1}, \dots ,\epsilon^{a_p}, e_{b_1}, \dots, e_{b_q}) \, e_{a_1}(w_1) \, \cdots \, e_{a_p}(w_p) \, \epsilon^{b_1}(v_1) \, \cdots \, \epsilon^{b_q}(v_q) \\
&= T(e_{a_1}(w_1) \, \epsilon^{a_1}, \dots ,e_{a_p}(w_p) \, \epsilon^{a_p}, \epsilon^{b_1}(v_1) \, e_{b_1}, \dots, \epsilon^{b_q}(v_q) \, e_{b_q}) \\
&= T(w_{a_1} \epsilon^{a_1}, \dots, w_{a_p} \epsilon^{a_p}, v^{b_1} e_{b_1}, \dots, v^{b_q} e_{b_q}).    
\end{align*}
At this point, I can only assume that Prof. Schuller was implicitly using the summation convention here, in which case everything works out right. Is that so? If not, where am I going wrong? Also, I would appreciate any insight as to exactly what the $a$'s and $b$'s are, and whether they're just dummy variables, because if we're summing over them then it seems so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Einstein summation notation is being used. Here $a_1,\dots, a_p, b_1, \dots, b_q \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ where $n = \dim V$. As you suggested, they are indices for the sums implicit in the notation. Without using Einstein summation notation, we would instead write

$$T = \sum_{a_1 = 1}^n\dots\sum_{a_p = 1}^n\sum_{b_1 = 1}^n\dots\sum_{b_q=1}^n T^{a_1 \dots a_p}_{b_1 \dots b_q}e_{a_1} \otimes \dots \otimes e_{a_p} \otimes \epsilon^{b_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \epsilon^{b_q}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, in defining the components in the first equation, there is no summation, and so the components are not treated as dummy variables, and that is where the "information" about the tensor is being stored, but in the second equation they're being used as dummy variables?

Comment: In the first equation, $a_1, \dots, a_p, b_1, \dots, b_q$ are fixed (there is no summation as there are no pairs of indices with one upper and one lower). While in the second equation, there is summation (because there are such pairs of indices).

Comment: I expanded the sum for a type (1,1) tensor and now I get it haha, should have done that long ago. Thanks for your patience with me!

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out.